# TextBox TextTrimming

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to apply a `TextTrimming` option on a **`TextBox`** (Not a `TextBlock`).

The compiler tells me that the `TextTrimming` options is not a valid property of the `Textbox`.

I could do a fancy control that is a `Textblock` and once it's clicked will become a `Textbox` and conversely go back to being a `Textblock` once the focus is lost.

Before going this way I would like to know if a built-in function already exists (or is there a smarter way) to allow you to do that?

EDIT: What I want to have in the end is a `TextBox` which is trim (the full content will be display in a tooltip) but when the user select the `TextBox` (enter in "edit mode") the full content will be display (without trim) therefore the user will be able to modify the full text. when the `TextBox` lost the focus (go back to "view mode") the content will be trim again.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using mvvm, you can trim the value dat gets stored in your properties. on property change, the value on UI is also updated.

Comment: @DDzire: I agree I could do that but I think it's really a display behaviour and I don't really want to put some trim logic in my viewmodel each time I want to handle this kind of display

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try a style like this (I've added background colours to make the change obvious):

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Background="Red" />
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Dan Puzey has a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10228419/975724), but I wanted to add more so that the style of the `TextBlock` *appeared like* a `TextBox`.

Here is the XAML style I came up with:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.044"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.060"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <TextBlock Padding="4,2,0,0" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This is what the control looks like when it has no keyboard focus:

[image: TextBlock - No Keyboard Focus]

This is what the control looks like after gaining keyboard focus:

[image: TextBox - With Keyboard Focus]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

I would use different control template: template with trimming when text box is not focused, whereas text box is focused I would use the regular template to allow text selection.
Needs to replace TextBox control template.

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
                 x:Key="ControlTemplateTextBoxNormal">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
        <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="ErrorElement"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    BorderThickness="1.25"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushError}">
                <Grid>
                    <Polygon x:Name="toolTipCorner"
                             Panel.ZIndex="2"
                             Margin="-1"
                             Points="9,9 9,0 0,0"
                             Fill="{StaticResource BrushError}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Polygon.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyleError}"
                                     Content="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </Polygon.ToolTip>
                    </Polygon>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          BorderThickness="0"
                          IsTabStop="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(behaviors:TextBoxBehaviors.WatermarkText), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                       Visibility="Collapsed"
                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                       Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       x:Name="watermark" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                 Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="watermark"
                    Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="ErrorElement"
                    Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <!--<Trigger Property="behaviors:TextBoxBehaviors.WatermarkText"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                TargetName="ErrorElement"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>-->

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
       x:Key="TextBoxStyleTrimming">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
            Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="ErrorElement"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                BorderThickness="1.25"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushError}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Polygon x:Name="toolTipCorner"
                                         Panel.ZIndex="2"
                                         Margin="-1"
                                         Points="9,9 9,0 0,0"
                                         Fill="{StaticResource BrushError}"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Polygon.ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyleError}"
                                                 Content="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </Polygon.ToolTip>
                                </Polygon>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                   TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(behaviors:TextBoxBehaviors.WatermarkText), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                   Foreground="Gray"
                                   x:Name="watermark" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                TargetName="watermark"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                TargetName="ErrorElement"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource ControlTemplateTextBoxNormal}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think wat you are looking for is this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=String, Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Trim:Argument:AnotherArgument}" />
```

I hope it helps :)

It will call the trim function and pass any arguments, if you want.
You can also use split and pass the delimiters as arguments.

You can find more on Binding.Converter [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx)

Comment: It will not work in the way I want. In your case it will be display correcly but I will not have a proper edit mode anymore (the user will not have acess to the trim part anymore).

Comment: wat exactly do you wanna achieve den?

Comment: apply the converter on the tooltip den, change its template to text block. TextTrimmin cn be applied on dat

Answer (score 0):

You may create a control template for your `TextBox` that display the usual editor when focused, and a `TextBlock` with trimming when it's not.

Comment: That what I was going to do but I wanted to know if something built-in already exist. I'll accept your answer if nobody come with a smarter way before the end of the day.