# ListView: Enable text trimming instead of HorisontalScrollBar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, formatting, string-formatting

I tried to search Google, but i cannot formulate it clearly enough.

So idea is: if text cannot be displayed fully in a `TextBlock`, end of text should be removed and '...' should be added. For fixed size i can write something like this:

```
DetailsListView.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}.{1} - {2}...", i + 1, j + 1,  somestring.Remove(15)));
```

but for dynamic WPF layout that looks ugly.

What the best way to do it?

---

i'm trying this one, but it doesn't work

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5" Name="TaskListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

just a scrollbar appears

[image]

Comment: Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx

Comment: If you are using WPF then this link might be useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/309927/WPF-TextBox-With-Ellipsis

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227014/textbox-texttrimming

Comment: Your title is very unclear - what do you mean: "Enable auto-remove when scrollbars appear"?

Comment: @markmnl now fixed, I hope

Comment: @Alex see my updated answer, need to disable horizontal scrollbar otherwise there is nothing to trim!

Comment: @markmnl I know, but property `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` is not intuitive at all and doesn't appears in properties. But thanks a lot for help, now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to do it yourself, `TextBlock` can already do this for you:

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
```

It seems your text is in a list of some sort you need to set this on the `TextBlock` in a `DataTemplate` for each item in the list, e.g.:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Of course if your `TextBlock` is in a pane that grows as it needs then there is nothing to trim - you can set a fixed size on your `TextBlock`, or your `ListView` and disable horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, should use ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock 
   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
   FontSize="14">
   One<LineBreak/>
   two two<LineBreak/>
   Three Three Three<LineBreak/>
   four four four four<LineBreak/>
   Five Five Five Five Five<LineBreak/>
   six six six six six six<LineBreak/>
   Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven
</TextBlock>
```

[TextBlock.TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)