# How to implement text-trimming for silverlight textbox as in textblock?

Tags: textbox, windows-phone-8.1, silverlight-5.0

How can i implement text-trimming for silverlight textbox to be used with windows phone project? I would like to add an ellipsis to the text content when it overflows the control.

Answer (score 0):

In the silverlight 5.0 , I have been using

`TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` `TextWrapping="NoWrap"`

or from cs use 
`myTextBlock.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;`

Hope this helps

Comment: my requirement is to use the text-trimming property on textbox, not on textblock

Comment: There happens to be no text trimming for textbox.Will using Multiline help `TextBox AcceptsReturn="true" `

Comment: Yes but i need a solution to use the same property(text-trimming) for textbox. so far i have browsed there is a way to do this for a wpf textbox(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227014/textbox-texttrimming), i need the same for silverlight textbox.