# UWP TextBox with ellipsis for long text when not focused

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm looking to create a TextBox in a UWP application that shows an ellipsis at the end of the text if it overruns the bounds of the TextBox.

What I need is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10228419/5723259), but for a UWP instead of a WPF app.

I believe I need to create a style that:

1. When unfocused, the TextBlock within the TextBox has a TextTrimming value of CharacterEllipsis.
2. When focused, the TextBlock within the TextBox removes the TextTrimming value (or resets to the default).

I am fairly new to UWP development and am unsure how to do this.

I have tried the following approach using `ChangePropertyAction`but I am unsure how to target the TextBlock within the TextBox:

```
<TextBox Name="myTextbox">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="LostFocus">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="?" PropertyName="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="GotFocus">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="?" PropertyName="TextTrimming" Value=""/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

I might also be going down the wrong path -- As a proof-of-concept, I have tried just customizing the default TextBox style to give the TextBlock control the TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" value, but this doesn't work (nor would I really expect it to, being editable text).

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: In UWP the suggest way to change the behavior of your control is using VisualState. To get start you need to create your own VisualState and go to the specific state when focused and unfocused. Here are some related info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager Can you start from here first?

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I was able to get a workable solution (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a workable solution with the following style derived from the standard TextBox.  Any comments on improving this solution are welcome.

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxWithEllipsisStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                            To="0"
                                                            Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                            Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            FontStyle="Normal"
                                            FontSize="12"
                                            Text="&#xE10A;"
                                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EllipsisContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EllipsisContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Grid.RowSpan="1"
                    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                    x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
                    Margin="0,0,0,8"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                    TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                    FontWeight="Normal" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                    VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                    IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                    IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                    IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                    ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                    TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                    TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"  
                    IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                    MinWidth="34"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="EllipsisContentElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                                TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"  
                                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```