# Spacing added when switching control template dynamically

Tags: wpf, textbox, textblock

I've implemented switching of `TextBox` with `TextBlock` on clicking. My goal was to show `...` when the text becomes wider than the `TextBox` width [I've followed this answer to come up with a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227014/textbox-texttrimming#answer-10228419). This is my current code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Height="24" Width="300" Cursor="Hand" BorderThickness="0"  Background="White"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding MyCustomText}">
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                            <TextBlock Height="24" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

To my surprise, on clicking into TextBlock, there is a small jump. Take a look:

[image]

I am not applying any `Padding` or `Margin`. Why is the reason for this jumping?

**UPDATE:** Default TextBox control template extracted with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBoxBase" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
  </Border>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
      <Setter Property="UIElement.Opacity" TargetName="border">
        <Setter.Value>
          <s:Double>0.56</s:Double>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Trigger.Value>
        <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
      </Trigger.Value>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver">
      <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
        <Setter.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush>#FF7EB4EA</SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Trigger.Value>
        <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
      </Trigger.Value>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused">
      <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
        <Setter.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush>#FF569DE5</SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Trigger.Value>
        <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
      </Trigger.Value>
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I removed the border completely and applied the style to every TextBox. The jumping persist

```
//merged dictionary 
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomTextBox" TargetType="TextBoxBase" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
    // triggers
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="TextBox.Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomTextBox}"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Update:** Apparently `Margin="2 0 0 0"` on the TextBlock is the magic number.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The sample provided does not match the default Template. I've extracted the default template (see updated the question) and it has no Padding.

Comment: There are unfortunately offsets which are not reflected in the template, because there is more content than the template shows. Here is how an unstyled `TextBox` looks in Live Visual Tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oecTW.png

Comment: Thank you! You deduced the offests based on width change or is there some way to see even deeper?

Comment: The offsets can be seen in Live Property Explorer. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhP9O.png  As far as I can remember, there is functionality like that in Snoop as well.