# Trigger content change on IsMouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the `Content` of `ContentControl` on `IsMouseOver` property set to `True`. This is the slightly shortened code:

```
<ContentControl Margin="2 0 6 0" Width="20" Height="20">
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage >
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        // drawing here
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>

    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentControl.Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Viewbox  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
                                // Canvas here
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>

</ContentControl>
```

Using Snoop, I can indeed inspect that the `IsMouseOver` is set to true, but the `Content` never changes. What am I missing here? Is is possible to change `Content` of `ContentControl` using Triggers?

Comment: The Content value set directly (by putting the `<Image>` tag into the ContentControl) has higher precedence than a value set by a Setter in a Trigger, hence the Trigger has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ContentControl.Content` in the style setter, too. The problem is that the style's trigger have lower precedence that the explicitly assigned value. You set the content explicitly (as a child), so it overrides any changes the style is trying to apply in the trigger.

Example:

```
<ContentControl Margin="2 0 6 0" Width="20" Height="20">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ContentControl.Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="Original"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentControl.Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
                                <TextBlock Text="Changed"/>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I don't understand what you mean with `You need to set the ContentControl.Content in the style setter, too`. I though I already did that. Can you copy paste the correct code in an answer?

Comment: @RobertSegdewick: Added a simplified example.

Comment: @RobertSegdewick: Glad that it helped!

Comment: It sure did. I opened another question yesterday that didn't get much traction. If you have time, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636936/error-when-switching-control-template-dynamically